SSRS Reports: Parameter Showing Only Two Values
I am working on an SSRS report and need help resolving it. In the data set, there are 2,000 rows of data and each of the 2,000 rows has 1 of 4 values in column X (see table below).
Column X     Column Y

0001          Include
0002          Exclude
0003          Include
0004          Include

Column Y is associated with column X and has only two values for each of the 2,000 rows. In this example, any row that has 0002 in column X will have "Exclude" in column Y and all others will have "Include" in column Y.
I need a parameter to only show two values, (1) Include and (2) Exclude. When the user selects either value, the resulting data set will either include or exclude data based on the selection.
Is this possible?

It is possible to credate a parameter that lets the user select one of the two values. Unfortunately it's not clear how the selected value will determine the records to be shown.

As you only have two values for the parameter, it's probably easier and faster to manually setup the parameter values.
Add a new parameter and give it a name (e.g. myParam). Open the parameter properties and in the available values tab select "Specify Values". Add a new value and set both the label and value to "Include", not add another value and set both to Exclude. Normally you would not do this as you would assign numeric values to the parameters but it will make it easier if we just match the data in ColumnY
Now, in your main dataset query, you'll need to add a where clause, so your dataset query might look something like this..
SELECT * 
  FROM myTable 
  WHERE [ColumnY] = @myParam

That should be it.
